# Dismissing a progress bar and stoping a background task(Thread) on click of back button in android

Tags: android

In a thread i am fetching large data from server and showing a prgress bar while data is being loaded, my problem is that on back press button i want to dismiss the progress bar and stop the background task, please note that there is no any loop in my background task thread to set as flag.i want to stop the background thread and dismiss the progress bar.

Comment: which thread you are using async task or other thread?

Answer (score -1):

You need to dismiss the progress bar and and terminate the thread onBackPreshed method of activity.

Here is some code that may help you.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try{
      progress.dismiss();   //may be NullPointer
      thread.stop();  // thread.interrupt  //you can check thread status then stop it. or you can interrupt thread
     }catch(Exception e){} 

     super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: I am using other thread , not async task, i want to stop background task thread

Comment: -1 you can put this answer in comments.. put your suggestion as an answer only when you have example or part of code.

Comment: I think Thread is Thread then What is "background task thread "

Comment: i have checked "thread.stop();" does not stop the thread, it showing that this method is depricated and showing this message in logcat